# Kalman filter eye tracking

Tags: opencv, tracking, kalman-filter

i'd like to implement a kalman filter using OpenCV to track eye (in particular eye ball). I read something around internet about Kalman Filter. I have to set the state of my filter. What can i use as state? My only available data are 3D coordinates of eye (x,y,z).

Answer (score 5):

You have to understand the Kalman filter first in order to use it. The most human readable intro with examples I have found so far is the [SIGGRAPH Course Pack](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf).

**UPDATE**

I do not know the Kalman filter implementation in OpenCV.

The state of the filter is perhaps the *true* coordinates of the eye. However, you can only *estimate* it from the frames (these are the coordinates you write in your question), hence the need for the filter.

To use Kalman filter as a black-box you will still need

1. an initial *estimate* of the state
2. measurement noise covariance `R`
3. process noise covariance `Q`

A reasonable estimate for 1. is the eye coordinates on the first frame.

As for 2. and 3., see *5.1 Parameter Estimation or Tuning* in the SIGGRAPH Course pack.

Perhaps the example *4.3 An Example: Estimating a Random Constant* will also help to understand how the Kalman filter works and what you need.

Comment: I already read it, but i can't understand at all what state could be for me! If i choose 3D coordinates as measure what about the state?

Comment: OK, I tried to clarify it, I hope now the answer is a little better.

Comment: I understood how a filter works in theory but i can't figure how to fit it on my problem. My state are real world position of eyes, my measurement are pixel coordinate obtained with eye detection, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, for a start you can go with that. The state of the filter depends on the process model. If you have a difficult process model you may need additional state variables beside the (x,y,z) coordinates. However, I do not know the OpenCV implementation and its process model / your process model.

Comment: If i choose my state as (x,y,dx, dy) where dx is the derivative of x, how can i set the transition state matrix to represent a linear motion?

Comment: This is a different question, namely what is the process model? I would expect OpenCV to offer ready Kalman filter implementation for this task, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. I am sorry I cannot help you with this, I do not know the OpenCV implementation. If you cannot figure out what OpenCV is doing then post a new question about the implementation details.